# HardwareSerial Indexing Array

Tags: serial, array

How should I index HardwareSerial ports into a single array?.

This compiles, but do not work.

```
HardwareSerial Serials[]={Serial,Serial1,Serial2,Serial3};

void setup(){
    for (int i=0;i<=3;i++){
        Serials[i].begin(38400);
        while (!Serials[i]);
    }
}

char s;
void loop(){
    for (int i=0;i<=3;i++){
        if (Serials[i].available()){
            s=Serials[i].read(); 
            Serials[i].write(s); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please, next time provide code that compiles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your code makes copies of Serials into items in the array of HardwareSerials. To use the original Serial objects, store and use pointers.

```
HardwareSerial* Serials[]={&Serial,&Serial1,&Serial2,&Serial3};

void setup(){
    for (int i=0;i<=3;i++){
        Serials[i]->begin(38400);
        while (!*Serials[i]);
    }
}

void loop(){
    for (int i=0;i<=3;i++){
        if (Serials[i]->available()){
            char s=Serials[i]->read();
            Serials[i]->write(s);
        }
    }
}
```