# How to create array of references?

Tags: array

I have a class named `timeOut` dealing with timeout tasks.

I'm to write a sketch, common for Sonoff basic and Sonoff Dual, meaning that I may have 1 task for Basic and 2 tasks for Dual.

Declaring instances looks like:

```
timeOUT timeOut_SW0("SW0",TIMEOUT_SW0);
timeOUT timeOut_SW0("SW1",TIMEOUT_SW1);
```

for code simplicity I'd rather create an array of references and call it using a `for` loop:

```
timeOUT TO[]={timeOut_SW0,timeOut_SW1};
```

is it the right way to call it as a reference ?

Comment: a few questions back I answered a similar question with example https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/67170/hardwareserial-indexing-array

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: @jsotola No it is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The C++ language [doesn't support arrays of
references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164266/why-are-arrays-of-references-illegal). You have the choice to either create an array of
objects:

```cpp
timeOUT TO[] = {timeOUT("SW0",TIMEOUT_SW0), timeOUT("SW1",TIMEOUT_SW1);}
```

or an array of pointers:

```cpp
timeOUT *TO[] = { &timeOut_SW0, &timeOut_SW1 };
```

Comment: `timeout_Switch:243:34: error: request for member 'remain' in 'TO[i]', which is of pointer type 'timeOUT*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
                         if(TO[i].remain()>0) {
                                  ^`

Comment: I upvoted this answer, and going to delete mine since it's wrong.

Comment: I chose 2nd option you offered